# Unable to select grandchild

Tags: jquery

I am struggling to understand why second variant in the below code does not work. Am I using the wrong selector or in that case only choice is find()-method or long chain of children()-methods?

```js
var list = $(".element-details-container.active");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  var $listElement = $(list[i]);

  var test = $listElement.children("div.content-module").children("input[id$=elementType]"); //Working

  var test2 = $listElement.children("div.content-module > input[id$=elementType]"); //Not working

  var test3 = $listElement.find("div.content-module > input[id$=elementType]"); //Working
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element-details-container active">
  <div class="content-module"><input id="details_0__elementType" /></div>
</div>
<div class="element-details-container active">
  <div class="content-module"><input id="details_1__elementType" /></div>
</div>
<div class="element-details-container">
  <div class="content-module"><input id="details_2__elementType" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.children()` method only searches 1 level down from the jQuery element it is attached to. So in your example, all of these selectors will return the same elements:

```
$listElement.children();
$listElement.children("div");
$listElement.children(".content-module");
$listElement.children("div.content-module");
```

No need to be so specific unless you had different classes on your child element you wanted to target:

```
<div class="element-details-container active">
  <div class="top-module"><input id="details_0__elementType" /></div>
</div>
<div class="element-details-container active">
  <div class="content-module"><input id="details_1__elementType" /></div>
</div>

<script>
  $listElement.children(); // $(list[0]) and $(list[1]) returns child element
  $listElement.children(".top-module"); // $(list[0]) returns child element
  $listElement.children(".content-module"); // $(list[1]) returns child element
</script>
```

Passing through a selector in the `.children('selector')` simply narrows your target of direct child elements. In your case, test2 doesn't work as `div.content-module > input[id$=elementType]` doesn't match any direct children, as you're targeting the grandchild element.

[Docs here to read](https://api.jquery.com/children/). Basically explains the difference between `.children()` and `.find()`.

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `children()` method is implicitly looping through all the child elements of `$listElement` and checking to see if they match the selector you provide.

As you're using a selector with a descendant operator in the second example, `div.content-module > input[id$=elementType]`, it is not possible for the check to return true. This is why the first example works; because you check each class in multiple `children()` calls.